# Why does tf.metric return zero?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, metrics, tensorflow-estimator

I have some code like this. 
It calculates the mean average error of two different outputs (*control* and *steer*). I want to define a metric that combines the two other metrics.

```
import tensorflow as tf

lambda_speed = 0.05

control_mae = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(ground_truth_control, predictions_control, weights=weights)
speed_mae = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(ground_truth_speed, prediction_speed, name='speed_loss')

mae_total = ((1 - lambda_speed) * nonspeed_mae[0] + lambda_speed * speed_mae[0],
             tf.no_op())

eval_metric_ops = {
    "mae_total": mae_total,
}
tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode, predictions=predictions, loss=total_loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
)
```

While debugging, I checked that the data and predictions look fine.
Sadly, I get a `mae_total` that is zero each step each epoch? Why?

Answer (score 0):

If I use metrics, I have to mention all metrics used in the `eval_metrics_ops`, otherwise they won't be run by tf.estimator. Like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

lambda_speed = 0.05

control_mae = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(ground_truth_control, predictions_control, weights=weights)
speed_mae = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(ground_truth_speed, prediction_speed, name='speed_loss')

mae_total = ((1 - lambda_speed) * nonspeed_mae[0] + lambda_speed * speed_mae[0],
             tf.no_op())

eval_metric_ops = {
    "control_mae": control_mae,
    "speed_mae": speed_mae,
    "mae_total": mae_total,
}
tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode, predictions=predictions, loss=total_loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
)
```